# AS3 game code keeps restarting by itself

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, restart

Hi I am currrently testing out this game and it automatically is restarting by itself without me even finishing the game... any help would be great!I dont really know flash that well so i cant really debug this by myself.

```
package{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event; //used for ENTER_FRAME event

public class Main extends MovieClip{
    const speed:int = 5;//speed of the snake
    var score:int;
    var vx:int;
    var vy:int;
    var gFood:Food;
    var head:SnakePart;
    var SnakeDirection:String;
    var snake:Array;

    public function Main(){
        init();
    }
    function init():void {
        //Initialize everything!
        vx = 1; vy = 0;
        score = 0;
        snake = new Array();
        SnakeDirection = "";
        //add food to the stage
        addFood();
        //add snakes head to the stage
        head = new SnakePart();
        head.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
        head.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
        snake.push(head);
        addChild(head);

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP , keyUp);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN , keyDown);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , onEnterFrame);
        //ENTER_FRAME listener is attached to main class and not to the stage directly
    }
    //This function will add food to the stage
    function addFood():void {
        gFood = new Food();
        gFood.x = 50 + Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth-100);
        gFood.y = 50 + Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight-100);
        addChild(gFood);
    }
    //this function will reset the game
    function reset():void {
        removeChild(gFood);
        addFood();
        head.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
        head.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
        vx = 1;vy = 0;

        for(var i = snake.length-1;i>0;--i){
            removeChild(snake[i]);
            snake.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    function keyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
           SnakeDirection = "left";
        }else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
           SnakeDirection = "right";
        }else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
            SnakeDirection = "up";
        }else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
            SnakeDirection = "down";
        }
    }
    function keyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
            SnakeDirection = "";
        }else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
            SnakeDirection = "";
        }else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.UP ) {
            SnakeDirection = "";
        }else if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
            SnakeDirection = "";
        }
    }
    function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void {
        //setting direction of velocity
        if(SnakeDirection == "left" && vx != 1) {
            vx = -1;
            vy = 0;
        }else if(SnakeDirection == "right" && vx != -1) {
            vx = 1;
            vy = 0;
        }else if(SnakeDirection == "up" && vy != 1) {
            vx = 0;
            vy = -1;
        }else if(SnakeDirection == "down" && vy != -1) {
            vx = 0;
            vy = 1;
        }

        //collison with stage
        if(head.x - head.width/2 <= 0){
            score = 0;
            reset();
        }
        if(head.x + head.width/2 >= stage.stageWidth){
            score = 0;
            reset();
        }
        if(head.y - head.height/2 <= 0){
            score = 0;
            reset();
        }
        if(head.y + head.height/2 >= stage.stageHeight){
            score = 0;
            reset();
        }

        //move body of the snake
        for(var i = snake.length-1;i>0;--i){
            snake[i].x = snake[i-1].x;
            snake[i].y = snake[i-1].y;
        }
        //changing the position of snake's head
        head.x += vx*speed;
        head.y += vy*speed;
        //collision with tail
        for(var w = snake.length-1;i>=1;--i){
            if(snake[0].x == snake[i].x && snake[0].y == snake[i].y){
                reset();
                break;
            }
        }
        //collision with food
        if(head.hitTestObject(gFood)){
            score += 1;
            removeChild(gFood);
            addFood();
            var bodyPart = new SnakePart();
            bodyPart.x = snake[snake.length - 1].x;
            bodyPart.y = snake[snake.length - 1].y;
            snake.push(bodyPart);
            addChild(bodyPart);
        }
        //display scores
        txtScore.text = String(score);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What did you find from your debugging when you stepped through the code?

Comment: I will start playing the game and then it restarts without me even finishing it! I couldnt find any problems when debugging

Comment: Are you able to actually step through the code? And are there any related logs? You don't have a specific programming-related question here, just some code and a statement that it's restarting "by itself".

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly just a question for "how do I fix this code?". You should try to provide an analysis of when your problem occurs. (i.e. whenever you turn right)

For your specific problem, try inserting [`trace`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#trace%28%29) statements at the different places where you call `reset` , so you can identify the source of your problem.

for example

```
    if(head.y + head.height/2 >= stage.stageHeight){
        score = 0;
        trace(">= stage.stageHeight");
        reset();
    }
```

---

If you're starting out game programming in Action Script, i would deeply recommend http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/as3-avoider-game-tutorial-base/. This is a great tutorial for actually learning how to make a game, as every step is carefully explained. You end up with a nice little game, but more importantly an understanding of how everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add `stop()` at the end of the code, or at the last frame, for the loop to stop whenever it's finished executing the code. Not really sure where to put it.